# Count with where and in also having LIMIT

Tags: mysql

I am fetching some records using in and having limit clause. like i have limit of 10. i am fetching 10 records from each **in** statement, Now i have where statement too. 
I want to count all records each in.

```
SELECT name from categories where id in ("23,34,56,78") LIMIT 0,10;
```

How to count total records in each id. 
Can we do it in mysql itself. 
Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I think I know what you want, but I'm not sure. Could you show sample input and expected output?

Comment: i want count from each id ie. 23, 34, 56,78.  total count

Comment: I asked you to **show** sample input and desired output. Your description isn't clear, please show what you want.

Comment: If your ID's are repeating then you can use `group by` but not sure since your description is not clear at all.